# How to change the Locale of epubcheck when using it as a library

Tags: java, playframework, locale, epub

I have a play! 2.4 webapp, that validates epubs with epubcheck 4.0.1.

The epubcheck.jar contains localizations for several languages.

When I run the jar from command line I get localized error messages.

```
java -Duser.language=es -jar epubcheck.jar some.epub 

Validación usando la versión de reglas epub 2.0.1.
INFO(CSS-007): some.epub/OEBPS/css/style.css(10,3): La propiedad 'font-face' OEBPS/fonts/ABeeZee-Regular.woff hace referencia a un tipo de fuente no estándar application/octet-stream.
INFO(CSS-007): some.epub/OEBPS/css/style.css(16,3): La propiedad 'font-face' OEBPS/fonts/ABeeZee-Italic.woff hace referencia a un tipo de fuente no estándar application/octet-stream.
No se han detectado errores o advertencias.
epubcheck completado
```

But when I run it as a library it always defaults to english.

I tried:

```
// set locale for translated messages
Locale locale = new Locale(language); 
Locale.setDefault(locale);
language = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage(); // is "es" now
```

How can I make epubcheck use it's other localizations?

EDIT:

I get the output of epubcheck like that:

```
// catch stderror output of epubvalidator
ByteArrayOutputStream ba = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(ba);        
System.setOut(ps);
System.setErr(ps);
EpubCheck epubCheck = new EpubCheck(file);
// .. get stdout as string
String resultString = new String(ba.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 11/12/2015**: I added code to support per-instance localization and issued a pull request to the EpubCheck repo. You can see the code here:

- [Localization fork on github](https://github.com/matthew-macgregor/epubcheck/tree/localization-dev)
- [Pull request](https://github.com/IDPF/epubcheck/pull/650)

I'll continue to track this and update this post with developments.

**Original answer:**

Epubcheck supports `i18n` internationalization since 4.0. You can check out the internationalization page on the [GitHub wiki](https://github.com/IDPF/epubcheck/wiki/Translating) for the project. Currently supports `en`, `ja`, `de`, `es`, `fr`, `it`.

The following code should do what you need:

```
File file = new File("/home/matthew/Desktop/RobinHood-1.0.epub");
Locale l = new Locale("es");
Locale.setDefault(l);

// Create a stream to hold the output
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream old = System.out;
System.setOut(new PrintStream(baos));

// Do epubcheck stuff...
EpubCheck epubCheck = new EpubCheck(file);
epubCheck.validate();

// Flush and reset output stream
System.out.flush();
System.setOut(old);

System.out.println("Result >> " + baos.toString());
```

The default output displays in Spanish now:

> Result >> Validación usando la versión de reglas epub 2.0.1.

**Edit**: Since `Locale.setDefault()` changes the JVM's global locale, it's not  appropriate for server-side use.

Comment: that's basically what i'm doing in the controller method, except the flush(). But sadly there is no improvement. I also tried implementing my own com.adobe.epubcheck.api.Report and pass it as a second argument to EpubCheck constructor. But still no luck. The MessageDictionary gets the locale like Locale.getDefault(). Even though i changed it before it's still english..

Comment: i don't know why, but now it works.. i'm used to code update like rails. java seems to miss out some code updates. I'm using the custom report now: com.adobe.epubcheck.api.Report

Comment: strangely it stays at spanish, even if i switch to italian or anything else..

i figured that I need to restart the server in order to get the language change. It only works for THE FIRST REQUEST. dangit! My java knowledge ends here..

Comment: Locale.setDefault() is also a JVM-wide setting so this probably is not what you need in a server context, now that I think about it. It's too bad you can't pass the locale into the library.

Comment: Yeah, just checked the source code for epubcheck. When it retrieves the message, it's simply grabbing the default Locale. There's probably no way around that on a per-request basis without making changes to the library. I may add that and issue a pull request.

Comment: Funny workaround: Set up different jvms, one for each language, still the same code though, lol!

Comment: antoher workaround: use our own reporter which uses your own MessageDictionary, which has a locale in the constructor MyMessageDictionary extends MessageDictionary

It's basically code duplication

Comment: Well, alternatively, you could always use exec() to start a new process just like you're doing with the CLI example in your question. I tested it just now with asynchronous requests and it seems to work correctly. It's a terribly kludgy way, but it provides a reasonable workaround.

Comment: The reason why you can only set the language once is because the messages are stored in a static variable, therefore only loaded once on assignment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94554/discussion-between-matsuzine-and-mojomajor).